# Difference between Account-level and User-Level Network Policies

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was reading the difference between Network and User level policies on this Snowflake Doc [link](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/network-policies.html). But could not understand what are they except how it can be defined. Can some one please explain.

Answer (score 1):

User-level network policies take precedence over account-level network policies. That means you can configure a user to connect Snowflake from a specific IP, or block his/her access from specific IP address. For example, you can limit your account admin user to connect from only a specific IP, while the rest of users can connect from anywhere.

Comment: Great answer.  So overall, the only difference is the level of granularity when you want to have more network policy control at the user level (as opposed to or in combination with a policy for the entire account).  Another minor difference is that you will only be able to set user-level policies via SQL as there is no UI interface for this currently.